# Can we use DynaTrace to monitor column value of a database table?

Tags: database, monitoring, dynatrace

I want to monitor column value of a database table. If the column value exceeds certain limit (say threshold value) then I want to generate some notification.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box.

You can write OneAgent extension to fetch data from database table and forward it back to Dynatrace. Only after that you can do some alerting.

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/extensions/oneagent-extensions/oneagent-extensions-hands-on/) from Dynatrace to write ypur own oneagent extension.

Comment: Can you share some tutorial or example? I am totally new to this. Thanks for the response.